# Why does Apache Spark executor cause OutOfMemoryError while writing something much less than the configured memory into a file?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm

I am trying to diagnose an OutOfMemoryError caused by Spark executor and hope someone might be able to help me here...

**Configuration**

I am running Spark (3.1.3) with local mode on my Windows machine.
My JVM instance is setup with memory of 2g.
My Spark executor memory is 1g (`spark.executor.memory`).

**Scenario**

I simply run a Spark SQL query against some parquet files in my local file system.
I want to test other part of our system to see how it handles one super long record (row) so I gave a Spark SQL query like:

```
SELECT repeat('A', 50000000) AS test
```

When I ran this query and wrote to a csv file, the JVM process crashed with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**Question**

To my understanding, the input data is roughly 50 MB (50 million characters), which should be much smaller than the configured executor memory space (1g).

I checked the heap dump and I did see lots of copies of this char array, resulting in around 800 MB of the memory usage.

However, if I use a different query with an even larger input (like 200 MB) but not with such a gigantic row, it was fine.

Is it normal for Spark to make so many copies of one single record? And is there any way to avoid this kind of OOM? Thank you

**Reference**

Here is part of the exception:

```
Thread 'Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 35)' with ID = 135
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    com.univocity.parsers.common.input.ExpandingCharAppender.expand(ExpandingCharAppender.java:115)
    com.univocity.parsers.common.input.ExpandingCharAppender.expand(ExpandingCharAppender.java:123)
    com.univocity.parsers.common.input.ExpandingCharAppender.append(ExpandingCharAppender.java:207)
com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvWriter.append(CsvWriter.java:405)
com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvWriter.processRow(CsvWriter.java:228)
    com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.submitRow(AbstractWriter.java:352)
    com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:830)
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.csv.UnivocityGenerator.write(UnivocityGenerator.scala:94)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.write(CsvOutputWriter.scala:46)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.write(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:140)
```

I have tried reading Spark memory management, but still could find related materials.
I have tried to cache the data and persist the data in disk only, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you seem to be running Spark in single JVM mode which is the *local* mode and not *standalone*, which is actually a clustered runtime.

In local mode, executor settings are not used and you need to specify your memory requirements on the driver either with `spark.driver.memory=2g` config or `--driver-memory 2g` spark-submit cli argument.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, this is the local mode. I have corrected the original post and will try to tune the driver memory instead.